# MSCRM 2011 - making relationships between many entities

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I want to create a custom entity linked to the contact entity.

The purpose of this new entity is to store competitors of a contact (it is not like the default MCRM competitor entity that as for purpose to store your own competitors).

I tried many ways to do that by creating an entity with single names of competitors & an entity linked to contacts to store competitors names but after, you get the "add a new competitor" & "add an existing competitor" that are refering to the second entity I created: you see the whole list of competitors including duplicates (if many contacts have the same competitor, you see many times the same competitor name).

Is it a relationship problem, or should I use an other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create a 1 -> Many relationship? E.g. When two contacts share the same competitor you create 2 competitor records.

Try using a Many -> Many relationship, that way two contacts can share the competitor record, e.g. you have 1 competitor record for 2 contact records.

This should reduce duplication.